# Journey Builder Engagement Split path based on a specific link click

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

When using Journey Builder I would like to split the path based on a specific link click in an email. In the Engagement Split decision window there is a drop down to select an email and either open or click. I don't see an option to select a specific link within the email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question.  According to SFMC, you can't do this with a simple Engagement Split.

You can, however, write a [Query Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) that references [_Click](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_click/) System Data View to populate a Data Extension of specific link clicks.

Answer (score 4):

Salesforce released an update to the Engagement split activity based on click activity of a specific url in email.

The engagement split activity sends contacts down a Yes or No path based on whether the contact opens an email, clicks a link in the email, or the email bounces. When a click, open, or bounce occurs, the contact who took that action proceeds down the Yes path

[image]

Here is the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_use_the_engagement_split_activity.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 0):

@victorcorey i implemented the exact scenario last week using Query activity that references _Click system data view. Kindly refer to the following link for details

[Creating link based decision splits](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/121240/can-a-query-activity-update-a-data-extension-in-real-time/121419#121419)