# Engagement Split Journey Builder

Tags: ampscript, journeybuilder

This question is extension of the [Can a Query Activity update a Data Extension in real time](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/121240/can-a-query-activity-update-a-data-extension-in-real-time/121419#121419)

I have a data extension configured for Journey Builder.It has one to one cardinality with contactkey in contact builder. The name of the data extension is Lead Gen. Now I want to split the subscriber based on a link clicked. The alias for the link is Interested.

I followed the solution from the [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/121240/can-a-query-activity-update-a-data-extension-in-real-time/121419#121419) and created a Data Extension (Facebook Interested Event) with the following fields.(snippet attached)

[image: Facebook Interested Event]

Now when I sent the email and clicked on the link the above data extension got populated. I have used the below query:

> SELECT SubscriberID, SubscriberKey, ListID, EventDate, Domain, URL,
>   LinkName, TriggeredSendCustomerKey FROM _click WHERE LinkName =
>   'Interested'

Now as mentioned in step 4, one more DE need to be created which should be used for decision split in Journey Builder. If possible can someone explain this step?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this solution is not required as in Journey Builder you can do the engagement split based on a particular link.

Thanks